# how can I use WCSessionUserInfoTransfer in watchos?

Tags: ios, data-transfer

is anywhere a simple tutorial, how I can use the `WCSessionUserInfoTransfer` to change data between my watch and iOS ?

And what must be written in the delegate of the iOS -App?

in my old programming I used:

```
[WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:@{@"Kommando":@"Radius"} reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error from parent: %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Radius from parent: %@", [replyInfo objectForKey:@"Radius"]);
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is to define a WCSession. This must be defined and activated in every class that you're planning on transferring data to and receiving data from. To use `WCSession`, make sure it's supported, and then activate the default session as shown below.

```
#import <WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.h>

if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
      WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
      session.delegate = self;
      [session activateSession];
}
```

From here, you can use transferUserInfo where ever you need to send data (from the watch or the iOS app):

```
[[WCSession defaultSession] transferUserInfo:@{@"Kommando":@"Radius"}];
```

On the receiving end, you would use `session:didReceiveUserInfo`. Note that this does NOT need to be in the app delegate anymore on the iOS app side, unlike `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest`. You can use this where ever you need to receive the data. Make sure to activate WCSession, as shown above, in the class where you have `didReceiveUserInfo` also.

```
- (void)session:(nonnull WCSession *)session didReceiveUserInfo:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)userInfo {
    NSLog(@"Radius from parent: %@", [userInfo objectForKey:@"Radius"]);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that at any point in time there will only be *one* WCSessionDelegate in each app and it will receive all the callbacks. It might make more sense to have a central class that is the delegate and have the information either relayed from there to the correct place, or for it to persist things and then notify classes that the app's backing data has changed.